# How to monitor package versions across multiple (Linux) servers

Tags: linux, apt, puppet, package-management, dpkg

We use Puppet for installing the base level OS and packages, but our own application packages are deployed manually by individual developers.

I'm looking for a web dashboard to view/monitor the package versions across all machines. Has anyone come across something that achieves this? The `puppet-dashboard` project is interesting, but it gives a node-centric view, whereas I'd like to see at the class level, e.g.

```
          Server 1 | Server 2 | Server 3 
   pkg1   v1.2     | v1.2     | *v1.3*
   pkg2   v.09     | v.09     | v.09
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/fr/  it will inventory the packages on your boxes.

Some people like to couple it with gpli

http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/en/about/features/ocsng-glpi.html

> Used with a IT and Asset Management Software such as open source tool
>   GLPI, you will have a powerful inventory and asset management software
>   with automatic updates of computer configuration, license management,
>   help desk and more.

Comment: Thanks, this is a useful tool. Seems a little heavy, but helpful to know what's out there

Comment: Yea - IF you were Centos you could use SpaceWalk - http://spacewalk.redhat.com/

Comment: Cool. SpaceWalk looks neat. Do you know offhand how it queries system status? I wonder if that could be adapted to look at `dpkg` instead of `rpm`.

Comment: Some searching led to this - https://www.redhat.com/archives/spacewalk-list/2010-May/msg00208.html

Answer (score 1):

This looks like OCSInventory does a SNMP-bulkwalk of the Host-Resources-Installed-Sofware-Tree.

If your software is being installed with a package mechanism that will work for you.

If it does not, you will have to code something yourself.

You could run a cron-job, that calls specific binaries and updates version information with a simple SQL-statement into a central DB.

If you are interested in just a few packages, you might code that query using dpkg-queries (or rpm-queries on RPM-based systems).

Comment: Thanks. I think your suggestion of `ssh ... dpkg-query` is the general approach I want; was hoping someone had already gone down that path and built some sort of simple UI.

Comment: Being a sysadmin is like reinventing the wheel - a few hundred times.